# Reading a text file line by line in Euphoria

Tags: text, io

I am trying to read a simple csv (comma separated text file) using [Euphoria langauge](http://openeuphoria.org/index.wc):

```
#! /usr/bin/eui

include get.e

integer file_id = open("myfile.csv","r")
if file_id != -1 then
    sequence input_data = gets(file_id)
    while sequence(input_data) do
        printf(1, "The string read is: %s", {input_data})
        input_data = gets(file_id)
    end while
end if
printf(1, "before closing..\n")
close(file_id)
printf(1, "after closing..\n")
```

However, it end with error at the end of the file and never reaches "before closing" statement.

```
type_check failure, input_data is -1
```

How can I make this detect end of the file so as to end the program normally? I tried checking documentation but could not find it.

Bump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declaration of input_data to object, like so:

```
object input_data = gets(file_id)
```

Were you to run the above code on [Phix](http://phix.x10.mx/), you would also get

```
while sequence(input_data) do
               ^Warning: probable logic error (always true)
```

which hints at the cause of the error, and a potentially infinite loop.

Also, your close(file_id) should be inside the if file_id!=-1 test.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: & Welcome to Stackoverflow!